# What is the legal role of a Christian baptism certificate?

Tags: france, religion

One of our friends was required to submit her Christian baptism certificate when preparing her documents to get married in France. I'm not sure why that was required, and I'm wondering what is the legal role of a Christian baptism certificate.

Let's say my Christian parents never baptized me, would I have trouble getting married or making other engagements?

Comment: By whom was she required to submit this certificate?  There's a note [here](https://www.frenchentree.com/living-in-france/getting-married/planning-a-religious-ceremony/) that if you want to have a Catholic wedding in a church, the priest may require these documents, but that's nothing to do with the law.

Comment: Likewise, [this guide](https://www.expatica.com/fr/living/love/french-weddings-a-guide-to-getting-married-in-france-101112/) describes documents needed for a civil wedding in France, and there's no mention of baptism certificates or anything of the sort.  I think your questions results from a confusion between the requirements for a *civil* marriage (set by law) and for a *religious* wedding ceremony (set by the church).  The answer to the question in your title is most likely "None".

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, France is almost militantly areligious in its legal and government systems.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm personally not confusing civil and religious weddings, but I don't have details about why she needed the document. She had a civil marriage and didn't have a religious one (AFAIK). Anyway, my question is not specific to her case, eventhough it prompted me, and I'm just asking in general.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge do you mean by "none" only weddings or all legal engagements in general? Also, are you only answering with respect to France specifically or does this generalize also to a country like the US? Are there countries you know of where it would indeed be a problem?

Comment: @shadi: Well, it seems clear that it has no relevance for weddings in France.  I have never heard of any situation in any jurisdiction where such a certificate is legally important, but I can't prove that there isn't one.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that a baptism certificate might be presented as evidence of the person's birth and parentage, if they don't have a formal birth certificate.